# MS ACCESS: How to filter report using combo box and query criteria

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a database that has 3 tables (*ListOfDevice, DeviceType, Employee*).

**ListOfDevice Table**

1. DeviceName
2. Device Model
3. DeviceType   ------> Referenced to the DeviceType table using ID and 
                       DeviceType.
4. EmployeeID   ------> Referenced to the Employee table using ID and FirstName.
5. DeviceStatus ------> This only have two values either Working or Damaged.

Some of the record does not have employeeID, and those are labelled "Damaged" on the device status field.

I created a query and named it as "QryDeviceLists" and inside this query I imported those 3 tables and begin filtering for the query and report result. I used the "Like" and Wildcard for filtering.

Example: `Like"*" &[Form]![FormName]![ControlName or Combo box name]&"*"`

What I'm trying to filter here is the *DeviceType*, *EmployeeID* and the *DeviceStatus*. And the way I want this filter to work is through combo boxes, I have a form which I named as filter and inside this form is 3 unbound combo boxes linked to the those 3 tables. And here is how I will generate a report:

- If I select a value from the devicetype combobox  either "Desktop or laptop" 
  and leave the other combo boxes blank then, it should give me a result of 
  either laptop or desktop with all the users and the device status whether 
  working or damaged.
- The same for the *EmployeeID* combo box, if I selected a name or employee ID it should give a result of the specific device assigned specifically for that employee.
- And for the device status combo box, it should give a result either working or damaged depending on the selection from the combo box.
- And by leaving all the combo boxes blanks it should show all the record of the devices whether it's a laptop or desktop, working or damaged, assigned to all employees.

Here are the problems which I'm facing when trying to pull out a report using the combo boxes.

- If I select a value from the Device Type and leave the employee ID
  and Status as blank, no records are showing. Same problem goes to
  Employee ID Combo Box, If I leave the Device Type and Status as
  blank, also no records are showing.
- If I leave all the combo boxes blanks then only the records which are
  labelled as Working on the Device Status are showing. This is maybe
  because the other record which is labelled as Damaged has no value on
  the employee ID field. Because when I tried to put a value inside the
  Employee ID field and regenerate the query by leaving all the combo
  boxes empty then all the records show up.

Note: I don't have any VBA experience, and I'm using Access 2013-2016

Here are the query SQL Lines `SELECT ListOfDevices.ID, ListOfDevices.DeviceName, ListOfDevices.[Device Model], DeviceType.DeviceType, Employee.FirstName, ListOfDevices.DeviceStatus
FROM Employee RIGHT JOIN (DeviceType RIGHT JOIN ListOfDevices ON DeviceType.ID = ListOfDevices.DeviceType) ON Employee.ID = ListOfDevices.EmployeeID
WHERE (((DeviceType.DeviceType) Like "*" & [Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] & "*") AND ((Employee.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] & "*") AND ((ListOfDevices.DeviceStatus) Like "*" & [Forms]![filter]![CboStat] & "*"));`

Comment: Do you mean I should post is using the Answer your question button?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused  a bit. Kindly please check my post if I done it properly.

Comment: One last thing: please describe what does not work with your current query or setup. Again edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from other forum which I can't mentioned it because I don't if it's allowed here. However, here is the SQL Line which I use to solved the issue.

`SELECT ListOfDevices.ID, ListOfDevices.DeviceName, ListOfDevices.[Device Model], DeviceType.DeviceType, Employee.FirstName, ListOfDevices.DeviceStatus
FROM Employee RIGHT JOIN (DeviceType RIGHT JOIN ListOfDevices ON DeviceType.ID = ListOfDevices.DeviceType) ON Employee.ID = ListOfDevices.EmployeeID
WHERE ((([DeviceType.DeviceType] Like "*" & [Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] & "*" Or [Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] Is Null)=True) AND (([FirstName]=[Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] Or [Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] Is Null)=True) AND (([DeviceStatus]=[Forms]![filter]![CboStat] Or [Forms]![filter]![CboStat] Is Null)=True));`

Thank you Mr. Parfait for your remarkable effort.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this pure SQL solution with `WHERE` clauses pointing to comboboxes (no `LIKE` expressions). And if comboboxes are empty, `NZ()` returns the field itself. No VBA needed if report/form is bound to this query.

**QryDeviceLists**

```
SELECT l.ID, l.DeviceName, l.[Device Model], d.DeviceType, e.FirstName, l.DeviceStatus 
FROM Employee e
RIGHT JOIN (DeviceType d
RIGHT JOIN ListOfDevices l ON d.ID = l.DeviceType) 
   ON e.ID = l.EmployeeID 

WHERE ((d.DeviceType) = NZ([Forms]![filter]![CboDevType], d.DeviceType)
   AND (e.ID) = NZ([Forms]![filter]![CboEmp], e.FirstName)
   AND (l.DeviceStatus) = NZ([Forms]![filter]![CboStat], l.DeviceStatus))

    OR     
    (
        IIF([Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] IS NULL, d.DeviceType IS NULL, [Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] = d.DeviceType)
    AND IIF([Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] IS NULL, e.ID IS NULL, [Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] = e.ID)
    AND IIF([Forms]![filter]![CboStat] IS NULL, l.DeviceStatus IS NULL, [Forms]![filter]![CboStat] = l.DeviceStatus)
    )

    OR    
    (
      IIF([Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] IS NULL AND 
          [Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] IS NULL AND
          [Forms]![filter]![CboStat] IS NULL, 

          d.DeviceType IS NULL OR e.ID IS NULL OR l.DeviceStatus IS NULL , 

          [Forms]![filter]![CboDevType] = d.DeviceType OR
          [Forms]![filter]![CboEmp] = e.ID OR
          [Forms]![filter]![CboStat] = l.DeviceStatus)         
    )
```

Notes:

- Depending on your setup, possibly a `Requery` call on form or report is needed (available as a macro command)
- Include a *Remove Filter* button on your form that uses the [SetValue](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/setvalue-macro-action-36dfca71-0d8c-40fc-8b9f-31cfe5f48aab) macro event and assigns to all controls the value `NULL`.

Comment: I'm sorry but when you type `Employee e` and `DeviceType d` what's the "e" and "d" stands for. I know it's a silly question but I'm a newbie so please try to understand me.

Comment: They are [table aliases](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm) allowing you to avoid re-writing entire table name. The `AS` is optional for tables: `Employee AS e` and `DeviceType AS d`.

Comment: Ok, so, what I did is I pasted all that SQL line to my query and I run it. But I still didn't get the desired output. Is it maybe because one of the other record has no complete details? like a record for a laptop device which is labelled as damaged. What I mean by that is, if I labelled a device as damaged then the employee ID will be blank because there is no current user for that specific device.

Comment: What was selected on the form? What showed up in query output?

Comment: I have 3 combo boxes inside the form. And here's the function which I want the form to perform.

Comment: If I select the DeviceType Combo and leave all the other boxes empty, then it should prompt me the a result corresponding the combo box selection. Which means, if I select a laptop device type it should prompt me all the laptop on my record regardless of the users and the status of the device. And the same way goes to the other combo boxes. But if I populate all the combo boxes it should give me one specific result only. However, if I leave all the combo boxes empty all records must show up.

Comment: And what happens when you run this solution per your combo box selection?

Comment: Here's what happen when I run you SQL line.

1. I filled up the device type and select "LAPTOP" from the  combo box and leave the rest empty
(Result: EMPTY) however, it should prompt all the laptop devices regardless of users and the device status.

The same with employee ID combo, and leaving the rest empty and the result is also Blank means no record. And if I leave all the boxes empty and run the code it only gives me the laptop which labelled as "WORKING" from the device status field.

Comment: See update. I believe you have to add conditions for missing (i.e. `NULL` values) as in SQL: `NULL <> NULL`. By the way, you are mentioning *Employee ID* but previous query uses *Employee FirstName*. I updated here. Be sure query fields match exact fields in combo boxes' rowsources (bound columns). Above was tested on my sample data. Please add yours for specific help.

Comment: Sorry my mistake when mentioned EmployeeID what I mean there is the first name. But I noticed on your SQL Line that you add e.ID which now my criteria became 4 instead of 3. Can you update your code and make a criteria only for DeviceType, FirstName and DeviceStatus. I tried to rectify it but it just got missed up.

Comment: You can do that yourself and test. In fact, IDs are better for query efficiency and maintainability. Bound your combobox to them but show names/types with hidden columns.